# Apparent close votes discrepancy

Tags: support, closed-questions, vote-to-close

I have encountered the following discrepancy related to a closed question:

[image: Close votes discrepancy]

Question was normally closed by 5 regular users (not hammered by a moderator). However, review history reveals only 2 votes.

What is the explanation for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two ways to cast close votes on a question (for users with sufficient privileges, of course):

- via the review queue
- by clicking on "close" below the question itself

The close-votes cast via these two methods are added. But only those cast via the review queue appear in the review history. Those cast on the question itself do not.

Comment: That explains it. However, I find it strange to differentiate the close votes based on source (a close vote is just a vote + reason regardless of how it is cast).

Comment: @Alexei, +1, and also Close-votes do not add to other review queues, like Low-Quality and First Posts (if the Q is listed in several queues at once). But this is the way how the system is built.

Comment: @Alexei  The pane at the top is not a pane "of close votes" per-se, it's intended to be a pane of reviews.  If someone reviewed the question and decided to edit, It'd say "Edit", and if they decided to leave it open, you'd see "Leave Open".  It's the manila box on the bottom that's the close votes, and they're all together.